# Rephrase this below message for turn off pop up blocker

Tags: user-interface, usability

can someone rephrase this below sentence so that the user can easily understand the below line

" Please turn off the pop up blocker by going to tools option > pop up blocker > turn off pop up blocker in the browser and try again"

Comment: Well, the phrasing depends on which browser the user is using, doesn't it?

Comment: This is not programming related...

Comment: Seems like this is also where they don't accept any answers.

Answer (score 7):

“We are still using pop-up windows, even though they're a usability disaster that everyone hates, and for some reason we're still trying to launch them without direct user interaction.

Because we are too lazy to make our site conform to the requirements of every modern web browser, we humbly request that you change your global browser settings. This will allow any web page to flood your desktop with unwanted browser spam, making your experience on the public internet intolerably awful. But it's worth it, right?”

(In reality, if you *really must*, provide a simple link that the user can click on to attempt to open the pop-up again. Every browser's default settings allow clicked links to open a pop-up. The user's settings need not and should not be changed.)

Comment: You, sir, just won one internet. Congratulations.

Comment: Make that two Internets.

Answer (score 0):

From your "**here we use only IE**" it looks like your on an intranet and stuck with something difficult/impractical to change.

An appropriate message would be;

> This site uses Pop-up windows which are disabled in your browser.
>
> To enable Pop-up windows please do the following:
>
> 1. From the Tools menu, click "Pop-up Blocker"
> 2. Click "Pop-up Blocker Settings"
> 3. In the "Address of website to allow" box enter your.site.com
> 4. Click Add then Close

(assumes ie7/8)